# Clustering "access-time" data sequences

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis

I have many sequences of data looking like this:

```
s1 = t11, t12, ..., t1m_1

s2 = t21, t22, ..., t2m_2

...

si = ti1, ti2, ..., tim_i

si means the i-th sequence, tij means the i-th sequence be accessed at time tj
```

each sequence has different length of data (m_1 may not equal to m_2),

and each sequence's data means that the sequence si was accessed time at ti1, ti2, ..., tim_i.

My goal is to cluster the similar access-time sequences.

I'm not sure whether I can translate this problem to a time-series problem.

For my understanding the time-series data like that each sequence's data means the value at that time like stock data, but my sequence's value means which time the sequence be accessed.

If it can translate to time-series problem, but there is another problem. The problem is that the sequence's access time is very discrete (may be accessed at 1s, 1000s, 2000s), so if I translate to time-series format, its space would be very large, I think this can't run cluster with some algorithm like (DTW), its time complexity may too large.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Hope you find the site useful.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, DTW would be quite slow, since comparing the first two series [takes `k * m_1 * m_2` operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping#Complexity).

To avoid this, and to more easily compare your sequences, you might somehow hammer them into the same format (thereby also losing information).

Here are some ideas:

1. Differentiate to obtain times-between-accesses, and build histograms with fixed bins across all data.
2. Count the number of accesses during each minute every week (and divide by number of times that minute-of-week appears in each series). Adapt to timescales of interest.
3. Count "number of accesses up until now". So, instead of having data points only when an access was made ("sparse"), you'd get a data point for every timestamp ("dense") showing accesses for every minute up to the current one.

#3 would be similar to an ["integral image" in computer vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table). After this, new summarization techniques open up, like moving averages, or even direct comparison (if the recordings happen in parallel).

In order to pick a more useful representation, you need to think about what is meaningful in your application.

After you get a uniform-length representation, you can use cheaper [similarity measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure). A typical one is [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) (but be sure to normalize first).